# C - program crashes when using free function

Tags: c, pointers, codeblocks, free

first, sorry for my bad english jeje. I don't speak it.

I'm having a problem when using free() function to free memory, this is what I have :

[image: Using free() function in C]

I'm using codeblocks on Windows 7. I have around 3 years using dinamic memory allocation and this is the first time I get this problem.
There are people that say that the problem is gcc compiler

[image: equal Directions]

Directions are equal in and out the function, so I don't think I'm trying to free an invalid pointer

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code as text directly in your question. Also please don't forget to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Checking if `M == NULL` after assigning some value to `*M` isn't good. See [EXP34-C. Do not dereference null pointers - CERT C Coding Standard - CERT Secure Coding Standards](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/EXP34-C.+Do+not+dereference+null+pointers)

Comment: I am feeling like opened Instagram...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors in the code is:

- `M == NULL` is not a valid way to check if `malloc` is succeeded. You should use `(*M) == NULL` because the value is assigned to `(*M)`, not `M`.
- The loop condition in `ReservarMemoriaMatriz` `i<=m` seems wrong. It should be `i<=n`.
- You forgot to free `(*M)[n]` in `LiberarMemoriaMatriz`.

Corrected code:

```
void LiberarMemoriaMatriz(double*** M,int n){
    int i = 0;
    if(M == NULL) return;
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
        free((*M)[i]);
    }
    free(*M);
}

int ReservarMemoriaMatriz(double*** M, int n, int ,){
    int i = 0;
    if(M == NULL) return 0;
    (*M) = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(double*));
    if((*M) == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    for(i = 0; i<=n; i++){
        (*M)[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
        if((*M)[i] == NULL){
            /* free what is allocated before failing */
            for(i--; i>=0; i--) free((*M)[i]);
            free(*M);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Lines 2-4 of ReservarMemoriaMatriz are still wrong, Presumably the caller is passing `&M` as the first parameter, and that can never be NULL. so the second line is meaningless. Line 4 should check *M for NULL, not M. And assuming the caller also passes &M into LiberarMemoriaMatriz, the same applies there, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop should be using `n` not `m` on your second round of allocation.

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++) // You're using m here: use n
{
    ...
    malloc(m...) // Here m is correct
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking line-by-line and finally found the mistake:

I like what you do that says:

> free what is allocated before failing

Another thing that I changed is when allocating memory I use:

```
(*M) = (double**)malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
```

and the loop condition, `i < n`, and everything is working fine.